# How to to set partition key for third-party cookies in c#?

Tags: c#, third-party-cookies

How to bypass third party cookies in C#? Now cookies are set with Response.Cookies.Append and cookieOptions like this:

`Response.Cookies.Append("SomeCookie", "SomeValue", cookieOptions);`

There is an instructions how to work around the third-party cookies at [developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/chips/](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/privacy-sandbox/chips/) - but this Partitioned property is not allowed in cookieOptions class. Is there any way to set custom keys-values for cookie using Response.Cookies.Append ?

Comment: Managed to solve this problem by overwriting the headers (Response.Headers.Remove("Set-Cookie")/Response.Headers.Add("Set-Cookie", updatedCookies)) in the middleware using Response.OnStarting method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is not yet supported in dot net, you can just append the `Partitioned` property to the Path option. For example:

```
Response.Cookies.Append("X-Access-Token", accessToken, new CookieOptions()
{
    HttpOnly = true,
    Secure = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Path = "/; samesite=None; Partitioned"
});
```

This code also includes a fix to ensure the option `samesite=None` is outputted into the cookie.

Answer (score 3):

From ASP.NET Core 7, you can use [the `CookieOptions.Extensions` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.cookieoptions.extensions) to append additional values like this to your cookies:

```cs
Response.Cookies.Append("SomeCookie", "SomeValue", new CookieOptions
{
    Secure = true,
    SameSite = SameSiteMode.None,
    Extensions = { "Partitioned" }
});
```

Comment: If you want to set it for all cookies, [you can use CookiePolicyMiddleware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77846869/2432538).

Answer (score 0):

Support is [planned for .NET 9](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/53224), released in November 2024. Unfortunately [CHIPS rollout is planned for Q3 2024](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd#report-issues), so we must use a workaround till then.