# How to set Partitioned attribute for all cookies in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, chips

As part of adapting to [the phase-out of third-party cookies](https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd), we would like to adopt [Cookies Having Independent Partitioned State (CHIPS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Privacy/Partitioned_cookies) across our whole application. How can we easily set the new `Partitioned` attribute for all cookies?

Answer (score 2):

We can use [the `CookiePolicyMiddleware`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.cookiepolicy.cookiepolicymiddleware) to add the `Partitioned` attribute to all appropriate cookies (those with the `Secure` and `SameSite=None` attributes):

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.OnAppendCookie = context =>
        {
            if (context.CookieOptions.Secure && context.CookieOptions.SameSite == SameSiteMode.None)
            {
                context.CookieOptions.Extensions.Add("Partitioned");
            }
        };
    });
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder application, IHostEnvironment env)
{
    application.UseCookiePolicy();
}
```

Comment: Perfect! This fixed my issues where I have a Vue 3 frontend talking to aspnet API and Identity Server.